# storcli - remove physical drives from a virtual drive

Tags: raid5, megaraid, storcli

Using an AVAGO Megaraid controller with the storcli command line software on Ubuntu.

My virtual drive has 8 10TB physical drives in a RAID5. I want to remove 2 of them so I can use those slots for another purpose. I have already shrunk the file system and the partition and have the device unmounted.

Here is part of what 'storcli /c0/v0 show all' gives:

```
    /c0/v0 :
 
--------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC      Size Name 
--------------------------------------------------------------
0/0   RAID5 Dgrd  RW     No      NRWTD -   ON  72.761 TB      
--------------------------------------------------------------
 
Cac=CacheCade|Rec=Recovery|OfLn=OffLine|Pdgd=Partially Degraded|Dgrd=Degraded
Optl=Optimal|RO=Read Only|RW=Read Write|HD=Hidden|TRANS=TransportReady|B=Blocked|
Consist=Consistent|R=Read Ahead Always|NR=No Read Ahead|WB=WriteBack|
AWB=Always WriteBack|WT=WriteThrough|C=Cached IO|D=Direct IO|sCC=Scheduled
Check Consistency
 
PDs for VD 0 :
============
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
62:0      9 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:1      8 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:2      4 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:3      5 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:4     10 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:5      2 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:6      0 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:7      3 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down/PowerSave|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported|UGShld-UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld-Hotspare shielded
CFShld-Configured shielded|Cpybck-CopyBack|CBShld-Copyback Shielded
 
 
VD0 Properties :
==============
Strip Size = 64 KB
Number of Blocks = 156254601216
VD has Emulated PD = Yes
Span Depth = 1
Number of Drives Per Span = 9
Write Cache(initial setting) = WriteThrough
Disk Cache Policy = Disabled
Encryption = None
Data Protection = Disabled
Active Operations = None
Exposed to OS = Yes
OS Drive Name = /dev/sdc
Creation Date = 30-01-2019
Creation Time = 09:29:58 PM
Emulation type = default
Cachebypass Mode = Cachebypass Disable
Is LD Ready for OS Requests = Yes
SCSI NAA Id = 600605b00e773a5023e4d3d60a8e8817
```

I thought that I could migrate with a command like 'storcli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid5 option=remove drives=62:0,62:4' however that complains that '0 MIGRATE   Failed   118 Operation is not possible'

Any suggestions on what I need to do here? Is it related to the degraded state of the array as a whole? I am not quite sure how to fix that.

Is it degraded because of the 'Number of Drives Per Span = 9'? I don't know how that happened but I guess I could have issued an improper command when messing around with the array. It never had 9 drives.